# How do I calculate the cummulative sum of count of strings

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqYig.png)

This the data. I have dates and the scenario IDs counted for each day. Now I want to calculate the cummulative sum

I tried using the code below,but instead of adding count of Scenario Id for each row it multiplies the total of the count of scenario ID by the count.

Cummulative Planned =
CALCULATE (
SUM('Table7'[Count of Scenario ID]),
FILTER (
ALL( 'Table7'[Projected LandingStart Date] ),
'Table7'[Projected LandingStart Date] <= MAX ( 'Table7'[Projected LandingStart Date] )
)
)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNf4k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give Table name in ALL, not Date column

```
Cummulative Planned = CALCULATE ( SUM('Table7'[Count of Scenario ID]), FILTER ( ALL( 'Table7'), 'Table7'[Projected LandingStart Date] <= MAX ( 'Table7'[Projected LandingStart Date] ) ) )
```